# complicated search design

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, search, search-engine

I am implementing a recipe search on rails3 using mysql.

The idea of search is that user enters any number of ingredients and search outputs suggestions what to make, sorted in product deficiency order.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
end

# these records will be entered by user
class IngredientType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
end

# this table is join table
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient_type
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

What would be the most efficient way to implement this search?
What gems or techniques would you recommend?
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def self.from_ingredients ingredients
    count_sql = Ingredient.
        select('COUNT(*)').
        joins(:recipes_ingredients).
        where('`recipes_ingredients`.`recipe_id` = `recipes`.`id`').
        where('`ingredients`.`id` in (?)', ingredients).to_sql

    where("(#{count_sql}) > 0").
        order("((`recipes`.`ingredients_count`) - (#{count_sql})) ASC")
  end
```

I managed to find solution by creating such method in recipe model.